# Spring Retry @Recover passing parameters

Tags: java, spring, recover, spring-retry

I couldn't find any info about a possibility of action I need. I am using @Retryable annotation with @Recover handler method. Smth like this:

```
    @Retryable(value = {Exception.class}, maxAttempts = 5, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 10000))
    public void update(Integer id)
    {
        execute(id);
    }

    @Recover
    public void recover(Exception ex)
    {
        logger.error("Error when updating object with id {}", id);
    }
```

The problem is that I don't know, how to pass my parameter "id" to recover() method. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

According to the [Spring Retry documentation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry), just align the parameters between the  `@Retryable` and the `@Recover` methods :

> The arguments for the recovery method can optionally include the
>   exception that was thrown, and also optionally the arguments passed to
>   the orginal retryable method (or a partial list of them as long as
>   none are omitted). Example:
>
> ```
> @Service
> class Service {
>     @Retryable(RemoteAccessException.class)
>     public void service(String str1, String str2) {
>         // ... do something
>     }
>     @Recover
>     public void recover(RemoteAccessException e, String str1, String str2) {
>        // ... error handling making use of original args if required
>     }
> }
> ```

So you could write :

```
@Retryable(value = {Exception.class}, maxAttempts = 5, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 10000))
public void update(Integer id) {
    execute(id);
}

@Recover
public void recover(Exception ex, Integer id){
    logger.error("Error when updating object with id {}", id);
}
```