# Kotlin with Spring-Retry the @Recover not called

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-retry

I'm having a problem using spring boot and spring retry, the @Recover annotation method is not being called when making all the possible attempts.

I'm using spring with kotlin.

My Application servlet container:

```
class ServletInitializer : SpringBootServletInitializer() {

    override fun configure(application: SpringApplicationBuilder) : SpringApplicationBuilder {
        return application.sources(SecurityServicesApplication::class.java)
    }
}
```

My Configuration

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.retry.annotation.EnableRetry

```
@Configuration
@EnableRetry
class RetryConfig
```

**Updated**

My Service

```
import security.commons.exception.SecurityException
import org.apache.commons.lang3.exception.ExceptionUtils
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value
import org.springframework.retry.annotation.Backoff
import org.springframework.retry.annotation.Recover
import org.springframework.retry.annotation.Retryable
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service
import java.net.ConnectException

@Service
class AuthorizationServerTokenRequester {

    val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Oauth2Service::class.java)!!

    @Value("\${accessTokenUri}")
    private val accessTokenUri: String? = null


    @Retryable(
            value = [SecurityException::class],
            maxAttemptsExpression = "\${server.oauthclient.retry.maxAttempts}",
            backoff = Backoff(delayExpression = "\${server.oauthclient.retry.delay}"))
    fun token(oauth2RestTemplate: OAuth2RestTemplate): OAuth2AccessToken? {
        try {

            return oauth2RestTemplate.accessToken
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            if (ExceptionUtils.getRootCause(ex) is ConnectException) {
                log.error("trying again....")
            }
            throw com.security.commons.exception.SecurityException("")
        }
    }

    @Recover
    fun recover(ex: SecurityException) {
        print("##############################################################################################sssss# SecurityException")
    }
}
```

**My Error Log:**

```
2018-08-10 11:28:41.802 DEBUG 40168 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : 
    Written [{timestamp=Fri Aug 10 11:28:41 BRT 2018, status=500, error=Internal Server Error, exception=org.springframework.retry.ExhaustedRetryException, 
              message=Cannot locate recovery method; nested exception is security.commons.exception.SecurityException: , 
              path=/security/api/v1/oauth2/token}] as "application/json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@21e2d8f6]
```

***Solution [with the help of @Gary Russell]***

**The return of the @Recover method must be the same as the @Retryable method**

```
fun recover(ex: S@RecoverecurityException, oauth2RestTemplate: OAuth2RestTemplate ) : OAuth2AccessToken {
    print("##############################################################################################sssss# SecurityException")
    throw br.com.totvs.security.commons.exception.SecurityException("")
}
```

Comment: I think `@Retryable` should be used in interface rather then class

Comment: @lukaszrys From the documentation is in the class https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry, retryable is working perfectly, Recover not being called

Comment: please have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46731031/5289288

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@Recover` methods must have the same return type as the `@Retryable` method.

**EDIT**

This works fine for me...

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableRetry
public class So51787951Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So51787951Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(Foo foo) {
        return args -> {
            try {
                foo.foo("bar");
            }
            catch (Exception e) {

            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public Foo foo() {
        return new Foo();
    }

}
```

and

```
open class Foo {

    @Retryable(maxAttempts = 3)
    open fun foo(data: String) :String? {
        println(data)
        throw Exception("foo")
    }

    @Recover
    open fun rec(data: Exception) :String? {
        println("Recovered")
        return null;
    }

}
```

and

```
bar
bar
bar
Recovered
```

Note that I had to make Foo and its methods `open` because Spring creates a CGLIB proxy subclass since there is no interface.

Comment: it did not work, I tried via interface and it also did not work, I added my error message, notifying that no recover method was found

Comment: I'm sorry, I had not read "return type", in my understanding I ended up reading parameter, I just debug the class RecoverAnnotationRecoveryHandler, and actually the return has to be equal "if (recover! = null && method.getReturnType().isAssignableFrom (failingMethod.getReturnType ())) ", thank you for yout great attention and support

Comment: @Gary Russell do we still need to wrap the call of "foo" in try/catch block, in our main ? I thought the retryable notation wraps it for us in its own implementation, and "Recover" method is the catch block